# Join with th same table SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to get VALUE_Expiration_DATE attached to DATE_EXPERATON
My table has 4 fields :

```
--- REFERENCE --- DATE (Production or EXPIRATION) --- COUNTRY --- VALUE --- 

---- 1  ----------------------- 1014 (production) -------------------- CAN   ---------- 105 -------   
---- 1  ----------------------- 0215 (expiration) --------------------- CAN    ---------- 203 -
.............................................    ............................................................................
```

My question is how to get the value of the 2 date PROD and EXP in the same row, this isn't working for me :

```
SELECT 
  REFERENCE
  ,@PARAM_Production_DATE AS Production_DATE
  ,@PARAM_Expiration_DATE AS Expiration_DATE    
  ,COUNTRY  
  ,VALUE AS VALUE_Production_DATE   
  ,**(
   SELECT 
      value 
    FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE REFERENCE <> 'XXX'
AND DATE in (@PARAM_Expiration_DATE)
) AS VALUE_Expiration_DATE** 
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE REFERENCE <> 'XXX'
AND DATE in (@PARAM_Production_DATE)
```

the row in bold doesn't work because it returns more then 1 value.
How can i do this please .

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: What is the primary key of the Product table?

Comment: So you know the two records belong together, because they have the same REFERENCE number? And you want to show all productions started at the given date? And you want to show production date and production country and production value, plus the desired expiration date plus the expiration value in case the expiration happens to be at the desired date (and null otherwise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot a reference in the subquery to the main query (i.e. make sure to access the same REFERENCE):

```
SELECT 
  REFERENCE
  ,@PARAM_Production_DATE AS Production_DATE
  ,@PARAM_Expiration_DATE AS Expiration_DATE    
  ,COUNTRY  
  ,VALUE AS VALUE_Production_DATE   
  ,(
   SELECT 
      value 
    FROM PRODUCT p2
    WHERE p2.REFERENCE = p1.REFERENCE
    AND DATE in (@PARAM_Expiration_DATE)
   ) AS VALUE_Expiration_DATE 
FROM PRODUCT p1
WHERE REFERENCE <> 'XXX'
AND DATE in (@PARAM_Production_DATE);
```

You can do the same with a left join:

```
select 
   production.reference
  ,production.date as production_date
  ,@param_expiration_date as expiration_date    
  ,production.country  
  ,production.value as value_production_date   
  ,expiration.value as value_expiration_date
from product production
left join product expiration
  on expiration.reference = production.reference and expiration.date = @param_expiration_date
where production.date = @param_production_date
and production.reference <> 'XXX';
```

Comment: how can i do otherwise to optimize the duration of the query? my database has much data. so it s about 3hours and still no result. is there any other solution?

Comment: You can try with an outer join. I've added this to my answer. In any way: make sure there is an index on REFERENCE or even on REFERENCE + DATE to have this query run fast.

Comment: Three hours sounds very strange anyway. As your IN clause contains one variable only it is the same as = (e.g. `col in (1)` is the same as `col = 1`). So the variable `@param_production_date` may contain `'1014 (production)'` for instance. How many entries with such value are in your table? Really that many?

Comment: TY for every thing @Thorsten. My query is a little bit complicated, I don't think i have enough space to right all of it , i've just tried to make an example more easier of it.